# Array as required field in PHP form not recognized

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I've got a PHP e-mail form to which I've just added an array of checkboxes. Data is coming through fine. However I want to make it so users have to click at least one of the checkboxes, but the current code I'm using to require fields isn't working for the checkboxes. The array of checkboxes is called 'formOptions'. This is the code I'm using:

```
$allowedFields = array(
'name',
'company',
'email',
'phone',
'comments',
'output',
'formOptions',
 );

// Specify the field names that you want to require...
$requiredFields = array(
'name',
'email',
'phone',
'formOptions',  
);


// Loop through the $_POST array, which comes from the form...
$errors = array();
foreach($_POST AS $key => $value)
{
// first need to make sure this is an allowed field
if(in_array($key, $allowedFields))
{
    $$key = $value;

    // is this a required field?
    if(in_array($key, $requiredFields) && $value == '')
    {
        $errors[] = "$key, ";
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to test for `empty()` instead of `$value == ''`.

But the real problem is that you're not testing any `$_POST` variables that aren't set. So while you ensure that a required field is not empty, it won't check a field that was not even passed to the script. Which is what happens when the checkboxes aren't checked, it's not that `$_POST['formOptions']` is empty, it's that **there is no `$_POST['formOptions']`**.

Instead of looping through the `$_POST` array, you would need to loop through the `$requiredFields` array.

```
foreach($requiredFields as $field){
  if(empty($_POST[$field])){
    //$field is missing
  }
}
```

If you don't want to change the current structure, you could just unset each `$requiredFields` when it's found, then if `$requiredFields` has any members left, they are the missing fields.

Using your example code:

```
foreach($_POST AS $key => $value)
{
  // is this a required field?
  if(in_array($key, $requiredFields))
  {
    if(empty($value)){
      //$key is missing
    }

    unset($requiredFields[array_search($key)];
  }      
}
//$requiredFields contains any missing fields
```

Or you could also just set some default values (`null` would work), and keep your exsisting code:

```
$requiredFields = array(
  'name' => null,
  'email' => null,
  'phone' => null,
  'formOptions' => null,  
);

$_POST = array_merge($requiredFields, $_POST); 
//any missing required field is now null
```

Then you just need to change your 'is required' check to:

```
if(array_key_exists($key, $requiredFields) && $value == '')
```

Note that I haven't tested any of the code samples.

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

```
   if(in_array($key, $requiredFields) && !$value)
```

**<del>and it should work</del>**

Edit:

it shouldn't work.  you need to place the loop that checks for required fields outside the loop for $_post.  to make sure you can check if a post key never exist.  see the comments below. see Tim comment.

Comment: Sorry, no dice...it works, as in if I replace that line it still recognizes that you haven't entered an e-mail address or name, but doesn't see the checkboxes.

Comment: can you paste the html part you use for checkboxes?

Comment: @pikelet That's because you're only checking the keys *in* the `$_POST` array - in the case of no checkboxes, that key isn't even passed - so it's not even being checked.

Comment: Tim is right, I didn't notice that.  you probably need to loop through the required fields differently, instead of putting it inside post loop